# Click event on Image control Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, image, events, controls, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently developing an app for ***Windows Phone 8.1***. As for ***Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1***, I wanted to bind a click event on an ***image control*** but it appears as there is no more ***Click*** or ***Tap*** event on an Image Control... Is it normal ? Does somebody already manage to get a click event on an image ? I've used ***PointerEntered*** method instead but it has a specific behavior...

Comment: The [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242752.aspx) control has a Tapped event that you can subscribe to. It should fire the event handler when clicked/tapped as long as it contains an image.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

`<Image Tapped="btnName_Tapped"
        Source="Assets/image_icon.png" />`

Code Behind:

`private void btnName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //your code goes here.
}`